# Wildcard String in Scala in .getOrElse

Tags: scala

What I am trying to do is grab anything that might be DECIMAL*

```
columnTypeMap.getOrElse("DECIMAL", Nil)
```

I dont want to hardcode something:

```
 columnTypeMap.getOrElse("DECIMAL", Nil):::
           columnTypeMap.getOrElse("DECIMAL(14,2)", Nil)
```

Data:

```
columnTypeMap: Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(DECIMAL(14,2) -> List(93, 98, 103, 125, 133, 145), DECIMAL(12,0) -> List(2), DECIMAL(6,3) -> List(110), DECIMAL(6,0) -> List(84), DECIMAL(13,2) -> List(104), DECIMAL(10,2) -> List(120), DECIMAL(10,0) -> List(74)
```

I am unsure how to do a wildcard in this case or pattern match in a statement like .getOrElse

Comment: What is type `DECIMAL` supposed to be? Can you provide a working example? Without further information it will be impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I just deleted my answer as I, mistakenly, thought DECIMAL was actually a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for collect and startsWith:

```
scala> val map = Map(
     |   "DECIMAL(14,2)" -> List(1), 
     |   "NOT_DECIMAL(12,0)" -> List(2), 
     |   "DECIMAL(6,3)" -> List(3), 
     |   "DECIMAL(6,0)" -> List(4))
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(DECIMAL(14,2) -> List(1), NOT_DECIMAL(12,0) -> List(2), DECIMAL(6,3) -> List(3), DECIMAL(6,0) -> List(4))

scala> map collect {
     |   case (key, value) if key startsWith "DECIMAL" => value 
     | }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(3), List(4))
```

Have in mind that these will iterate through all the values in the map. If you need more performance then you should use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: One last question is how would I make them all one list rather than a iterable of lists.

Comment: That's what flatten is for. `List(List(1), List(2)).flatten` is `List(1, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this with using the [TreeMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap) datastructure coming with the scala standard library:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable._

scala> val map = TreeMap(
 | "DECIMAL(14,2)" -> List(1),
 | "NOT_DECIMAL(12,0)" -> List(2),
 | "DECIMAL(6,3)" -> List(3),
 | "DECIMAL(6,0)" -> List(4))
map: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String,List[Int]] = Map(DECIMAL(14,2) -> List(1), DECIMAL(6,0) -> List(4), DECIMAL(6,3) -> List(3), NOT_DECIMAL(12,0) -> List(2))

scala> map.range("DECIMAL", "DECIMAM")
res5: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String,List[Int]] = Map(DECIMAL(14,2) -> List(1), DECIMAL(6,0) -> List(4), DECIMAL(6,3) -> List(3))
```